# accessing element attributes with jquery vs. plain javascript, which is faster?

Tags: jquery, performance

Which is faster: `$("#element")[0].value` or `$("#element").val()`?  If the former is faster, what is the purpose of the latter?

Comment: Implementation hiding and encapsulation, plain and simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$("#element")[0].value` is faster, native code is *always* faster.

Even faster would be `document.getElementById("element").value`.

The [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function is to work for all input types, including `<textarea>` and `<select>` elements.  Underneath, for everything that's [not an `<option>`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/attributes.js#L143) or [a `<select>`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/attributes.js#L151) or [a `<input type="radio">`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/attributes.js#L187) (in some cases) it [gets the `.value`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/attributes.js#L193).

Comment: E.g., the *value* (ahem) of `.val()` is that it smooths out some differences for you that you'd otherwise have to handle yourself.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I tried to enumerate all of those above, hopefully it helps a bit.

Comment: @T.J., @Nick - Are you aware of any other `<select>` issues besides the IE6 issue where its `<option>` elements don't have a `value` attribute? That's the only one I know about.

Comment: @patrick - IE has issues where you can't set a `<select>` element's `.innerHTML` to update the `<option>` list properly, but that's a result of them inheriting from the windows form control....BRILLIANT idea that was (same reason it's on top of everything but an `<iframe>`.

Comment: I see.  In that case would you recommend using the first (or even document.getElementById()) at all times, or is it okay to use the framework functions for consistency and sensibility?  That is, will the speed of the code suffer noticeably?

Comment: @tandu - unless you're doing this thousands of times in a loop, no I wouldn't worry about it.  If you are using an element over and over again, store it as a variable though, there's no sense is re-running a selector you just ran :)

Comment: @patrick: Well, aside from handling `select` for you (it doesn't matter whether `option` has a `value` attribute, the one on `select` [if there] usually isn't want you want, esp. for multi-select boxes), a quick glance at the jQuery source indicates it's working around some issues on Blackberry and WebKit. Which I didn't know, but that's kind of the point. :-)

Comment: @T.J. - Thanks for the reply. I was more wondering about when it's safe to use the `.value` property of a `select` instead of `.val()` to get the selected option's value. The exception I knew about was in IE6 where if an `option` doesn't have a `.value` attribute, it won't default automatically to its text content. It appears that it is actually the case for all IE versions. I looked at the jQuery source, and it doesn't use the `.value` property of the `select`. It loops through the `options`. I don't know of anything else that would keep me from using `.value` of a `select` (non multiple).:o)

Answer (score 1):

the same as `$("#element")` being slower than `document.getElementById('element');`

ease of use, consistency in the framework, hiding of cross-browser implementation (*inconsistencies, not in the particular example but that is the concept of frameworks*)..